# Entity Framework id probleme

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, one-to-many

I have a question about EF id, for example, I have a `student` table which has 3 students with id 1, 2 and 3.

If I delete student with `id=2`, then I add new student `id=4`, the id will be 4, but id 2 hasn't been there any more, so I want each time when I add new record, the id will always be the available and minimum number, is it possible?

E.g I have a class called `student`

```
public class Student
{
   public int StudentId;
   public string Name;
}
```

Comment: NO, this is **not** a good idea. **DO NOT** recycle ID's ! There's unique identifiers for a given student - don't reuse them. SQL Server just uses `INT IDENTITY` and gives you unique and ever-increasing ID values - just use those and get on with your programming.

Comment: no i have unique Id, but for example, i delete id 1,2,3 there is nothing in my datebase, and when i add a new record, id will be 4, i just want it to be 1 again

Comment: Again: **don't do that!** it's ***NOT*** a good idea to "recycle" ID's that have been used already!